# How to insert a new button in the comment box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my question I hope you can help me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9QAP.png

Or if you prefer you can see the text:

```
<div class = "markItUpHeader">
  <Ul>
    <Li class = "markItUpButton markItUpButton1 mark-youtube">
      <a href="" title="Insertar video video (Ctrl+Y)"> Insert (Ctrl + Y) </a>
    </Li>
    <Li class = "markItUpButton markItUpButton2 mark-image">
      <a href="" title="Agregar image"> Add </a> Image
    </Li>
    <Li class = "markItUpButtonmarkItUpButton3 mark-emoji">
      <a href="" title="Insertar Emoticon"> Insert smiley </a>
    </Li>
  </Ul>
</Div>
```

The code is one of the 3 buttons (Video, Image emoticon), I do not want to do a hack or anything like that, is simply to make it look me in my browser and more comfortable to use that site.

Excuse me if I do not understand but I write this from a translator because I am a Hispanic speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on what you want the buttons to do, versus what they currently do?

Comment: cryptic_star By clicking on the image button in the text box will this: '[img=]' what I want is to create a button to click to give me leave this: [b] [/ b] website is not mine and I love you so alone in my browser.

Comment: See this link to get more details here.
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tesag.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to maintain the code when you use the console, because it is only a tool that helps you temporally.
The only way is to have the code and to insert permanently the changes that you want to do.

If you have this code, you can make this:

```js
function insertB (){
    document.getElementById("texto").value = "<b></b>";
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="texto" />
 <input type="button" onclick="insertB()" value="B"/>
```

Comment: See this link to get more details here. 
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tesag.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've reviwed your link, and there is noy way to edit that website without you actually getting into the source code. The editor in the bottom in just an element inspector, which means it does not actually let you save the code (or else anyone can shut Google.com down in 5 seconds).

But if you still want to know how to add 'b' tags on click of a button, this code below is totally acceptable for that.

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but if you want the 'b' tags to appear on the text box,  [Here is the jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/70ndknwc/1/)

In summary, in the head, you need to call the jQuery usage. You also need to add the tags every time the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ButtonID").click(function(){
        var textbox = $("input:text").val();
        $("input:text").val(textbox + " <b> </b>")       
    })
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: See this link to get more details here.
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tesag.png)

Comment: and there is a supplement / extension to save it? as greasemonkey?